# CORS with WCF and windows authentication

Tags: wcf, windows-authentication, cors

Is it possible to handle "Cross Origin Resource Sharing" requests for a WCF service while enforcing Windows Authentication?

My scenario:

1. I have set up a self hosted WCF service exposed through a webHttpBinding.
2. This service is supposed to be called directly from the browser using jQuery. Practically speaking, this would limit me to using either the basicHttpBinding or the webHttpBinding. In this case, I'm using the webHttpBinding for calling the service operations.
3. The HTML pages (that will call the WCF service) are served from a web-server on the same machine but on a different port than the WCF service. This means I'll need CORS support to get this working in Firefox, Chrome, ...
4. Users must authenticate using Windows authentication when calling the WCF service. To this end, I have configured my webHttpBinding to use the transport security mode "TransportCredentialsOnly".

The W3C dictates that CORS should be used in such cases.
Simply stated, this means that the browser will detect that I am doing a cross-domain request. Before actually sending the request to my WCF service, it will send a so-called "preflight" request to my WCF service URL. This preflight request uses the HTTP method "OPTIONS" and asks whether the originating URL (= the webserver that served my HTML) is allowed to send the request to my service URL. The browser then expects an HTTP 200 response (= "OK") before sending the actual request to my WCF service. Any other reply from my service will prevent the actual request from being sent.

CORS is not built into WCF at this time, so I've used WCF extension points to add CORS compatibility.

The services section of the App.Config for my self-hosted service:

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior name="MyApp.DefaultServiceBehavior">
        <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>
        <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="True"/>
      </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
    <endpointBehaviors>
      <behavior name="MyApp.DefaultEndpointBehavior">
        <webHttp/>
      </behavior>
    </endpointBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
  <bindings>
    <webHttpBinding>
      <binding name="MyApp.DefaultWebHttpBinding">
        <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
          <transport clientCredentialType="Windows"/>
        </security>
      </binding>
    </webHttpBinding>
  </bindings>
  <services>
    <service 
      name="MyApp.FacadeLayer.LookupFacade"
      behaviorConfiguration="MyApp.DefaultServiceBehavior"
      >
      <endpoint
        contract="MyApp.Services.ILookupService"
        binding="webHttpBinding"
        bindingConfiguration="MyApp.DefaultWebHttpBinding"
        address=""
        behaviorConfiguration="MyApp.DefaultEndpointBehavior"
        >
      </endpoint>
      <host>
        <baseAddresses>
          <add baseAddress="http://localhost/Temporary_Listen_Addresses/myapp/LookupService"/>
        </baseAddresses>
      </host>
    </service>
  </services>
</system.serviceModel>
```

I have implemented an IDispatchMessageInspector that replies to preflight messages:

```
public class CORSSupport : IDispatchMessageInspector
{
    private Dictionary<string, string> requiredHeaders;

    public CORSSupport(Dictionary<string, string> requiredHeaders)
    {
        this.requiredHeaders = requiredHeaders ?? new Dictionary<string, string>();
    }

    public object AfterReceiveRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel, InstanceContext instanceContext)
    {
        HttpRequestMessageProperty httpRequest = request.Properties["httpRequest"] as HttpRequestMessageProperty;

        if (httpRequest.Method.ToUpper() == "OPTIONS")
            instanceContext.Abort();

        return httpRequest;
    }

    public void BeforeSendReply(ref Message reply, object correlationState)
    {
        HttpRequestMessageProperty httpRequest = correlationState as HttpRequestMessageProperty;
        HttpResponseMessageProperty httpResponse = reply.Properties["httpResponse"] as HttpResponseMessageProperty;

        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> item in this.requiredHeaders)
            httpResponse.Headers.Add(item.Key, item.Value);

        string origin = httpRequest.Headers["origin"];
        if (origin != null)
            httpResponse.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", origin);

        if (httpRequest.Method.ToUpper() == "OPTIONS")
            httpResponse.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.NoContent;
    }
}
```

This IDispatchMessageInspector is registered through a custom IServiceBehavior attribute.

I call my service through jQuery like so:

```
$.ajax(
    {
        url: 'http://localhost/Temporary_Listen_Addresses/myapp/LookupService/SomeLookup',
        type: 'GET',
        xhrFields:
            {
                withCredentials: true
            }
    }
)
.done(function () { alert('Yay!'); })
.error(function () { alert('Nay!'); });
```

This works in IE10 and Chrome (I get a message box saying "Yay!"), but not in Firefox. In Firefox, I get a "Nay!" and a HTTP 401 (unauthorized) error.

This 401 is due to the "Windows Authentication" that I have set up in my service configuration. The way authentication works is the browser first sends a request without any authentication info. The server then replies back with HTTP 401 (unauthorized) indicating the authentication method to use. The browser would then normally re-submit the request including the user-credentials (after which the request would proceed normally).

Unfortunately, it seems the W3C has indicated that credentials should not be passed into the CORS preflight messages. Hence, WCF replies back with a HTTP 401. It seems that Chrome somehow does send the credentials in the preflight request header (which is actually incorrect, according to W3C specs), while Firefox does not.
Furthermore, the W3C recognizes only the HTTP 200 response to a preflight requests: any other response (such as the HTTP 401 I receive) simply means the CORS request failed and the actual request may not be submitted...

I don't know how to get this (simple) scenario working. Can anyone help?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Well, yes...
First off I just configured my service to use basicHttpBinding with Windows authentication and tried to access it from my HTML page (using jQuery) -> HTTP 401.
Also wrote a IDispatchMessageInspector to handle the CORS preflight messages and added it as a behavior on my WCF service: no luck. It would appear that the browsers don't do Windows authentication for the preflight messages. Hence, the message doesn't even arrive in my IDispatchMessageInspector => still HTTP 401.

Comment: That was a rhetorical question.  You need to post your existing code/config as part of your question before anybody can help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eureka (kind of). It seems that Firefox didn't like the "Negotiate" authentication I specified for my service. It seems to work when I change the authentication scheme from "Negotiate, Anonymous" to "Ntlm, Anonymous":

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior name="MyApp.DefaultServiceBehavior">
        <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>
        <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="True"/>
        <serviceAuthenticationManager authenticationSchemes="Ntlm, Anonymous"/>
      </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
    <endpointBehaviors>
      <behavior name="MyApp.DefaultEndpointBehavior">
        <webHttp/>
      </behavior>
    </endpointBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
  <bindings>
    <webHttpBinding>
      <binding name="MyApp.DefaultWebHttpBinding">
        <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
          <transport clientCredentialType="InheritedFromHost"/>
        </security>
      </binding>
    </webHttpBinding>
  </bindings>
  <services>
    <service 
      name="MyApp.FacadeLayer.LookupFacade"
      behaviorConfiguration="MyApp.DefaultServiceBehavior"
      >
      <endpoint
        contract="MyApp.Services.ILookupService"
        binding="webHttpBinding"
        bindingConfiguration="MyApp.DefaultWebHttpBinding"
        address=""
        behaviorConfiguration="MyApp.DefaultEndpointBehavior"
        >
      </endpoint>
      <host>
        <baseAddresses>
          <add baseAddress="http://localhost/Temporary_Listen_Addresses/myapp/LookupService"/>
        </baseAddresses>
      </host>
    </service>
  </services>
</system.serviceModel>
```

I thought Firefox supported the "Negotiate" scheme... Anyone has any idea why it didn't work?

Answer (score 0):

Gotten a bit further.

With .NET 4.5, it is possible to support multiple authentication schemes for a single endpoint. This allowed me to define both Windows authentication and anonymous authentication simultaneously:

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior name="MyApp.DefaultServiceBehavior">
        <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>
        <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="True"/>
        <serviceAuthenticationManager authenticationSchemes="Negotiate, Anonymous"/>
      </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
    <endpointBehaviors>
      <behavior name="MyApp.DefaultEndpointBehavior">
        <webHttp/>
      </behavior>
    </endpointBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
  <bindings>
    <webHttpBinding>
      <binding name="MyApp.DefaultWebHttpBinding">
        <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
          <transport clientCredentialType="InheritedFromHost"/>
        </security>
      </binding>
    </webHttpBinding>
  </bindings>
  <services>
    <service 
      name="MyApp.FacadeLayer.LookupFacade"
      behaviorConfiguration="MyApp.DefaultServiceBehavior"
      >
      <endpoint
        contract="MyApp.Services.ILookupService"
        binding="webHttpBinding"
        bindingConfiguration="MyApp.DefaultWebHttpBinding"
        address=""
        behaviorConfiguration="MyApp.DefaultEndpointBehavior"
        >
      </endpoint>
      <host>
        <baseAddresses>
          <add baseAddress="http://localhost/Temporary_Listen_Addresses/myapp/LookupService"/>
        </baseAddresses>
      </host>
    </service>
  </services>
</system.serviceModel>
```

This way, my IDispatchMessageInspector does get called and I can properly handle the preflight messages for all browsers.

I then wanted to adapt my IDispatchMessageInspector to enforce authentication for any request other than the preflights:

```
public class CrossOriginResourceSharingMessageInspector : IDispatchMessageInspector
{
    private Dictionary<string, string> requiredHeaders;

    public CrossOriginResourceSharingMessageInspector(Dictionary<string, string> requiredHeaders)
    {
        this.requiredHeaders = requiredHeaders ?? new Dictionary<string, string>();
    }

    public object AfterReceiveRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel, InstanceContext instanceContext)
    {
        HttpRequestMessageProperty httpRequestHeader = request.Properties[HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name] as HttpRequestMessageProperty;

        if (httpRequestHeader.Method.ToUpper() == "OPTIONS")
            instanceContext.Abort();

        else if (httpRequestHeader.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Authorization] == null)
            instanceContext.Abort();

        return httpRequestHeader;
    }

    public void BeforeSendReply(ref Message reply, object correlationState)
    {
        HttpRequestMessageProperty httpRequestHeader = correlationState as HttpRequestMessageProperty;
        HttpResponseMessageProperty httpResponseHeader = reply.Properties[HttpResponseMessageProperty.Name] as HttpResponseMessageProperty;

        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> item in this.requiredHeaders)
            httpResponseHeader.Headers.Add(item.Key, item.Value);

        string origin = httpRequestHeader.Headers["origin"];
        if (origin != null)
            httpResponseHeader.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", origin);

        string method = httpRequestHeader.Method;
        if (method.ToUpper() == "OPTIONS")
        {
            httpResponseHeader.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.NoContent;
        }

        else if (httpRequestHeader.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Authorization] == null)
        {
            httpResponseHeader.StatusDescription = "Unauthorized";
            httpResponseHeader.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
        }
    }
}
```

Again, this seems to work for IE and Chrome, but not for Firefox. Preflight is now ok for Firefox, but it seems Firefox is not re-submitting the request after I replied with a HTTP 401 when the actual request didn't contain user credentials. In fact, I would expect Firefox to send the credentials along with the GET request immediately (seeing as I added "withCredentials: true" in my jQuery AJAX request; Chrome does seem to do this correctly, though).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you ever get this to work? Taking a quick look at the code, I would think that you would have to add WWW-Authentication headers, not just a StatusCode of UnAuthorized.

Comment: No, never got it to work... In the end, I decided to abandon this entire technique.

Comment: What did you use instead?